# Force TeamCity to use SVN Export

Tags: svn, teamcity

How can you make TeamCity to run `svn export` instead of `svn checkout`?
At the build configuration you have **VCS checkout mode** with the options:

- Prefer to checkout files on agent (recommended)
- Always checkout files on server
- Always checkout files on agent
- Do not checkout files automatically

But nothing seem to fit.

I'm asking because the duration of `svn checkout` is way longer than `svn export`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server-side checkout could be considered a rough equivalent of svn export, as .svn directories are not created in this case.

Another thing you may want to consider - using a native svn checkout, please read more in this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-51254

Regards,

Comment: From what I understand 'checkout on server' does a svn export 
and 'checkout on agent' does a svn checkout.

Is there a way to do an svn export on the agent, 
eventually adding the --force if needed?

Comment: @Ken, unfortunately, there is no way to do it unless you handle checkout manually, using revisions provided by TeamCity. Why would you need it?

Comment: We have repositories that contains a bunch of root files and folders that are needed in a lot of other projects. We checkout the project and this common repository to the same root to ensure all the files are available. Eg. each of the nodejs versions is available in a repository so we can switch/include the correct version depending on the project that needs it and also easily test an upgrade.

Comment: @Ken Thanks for the answer. I'm afraid server-side checkout or manual checkout are the only options in your case, sorry